# Path doesn't exist error, even though the path clearly does exist

Tags: python

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhqrC.png)
This error keeps popping up and I cant find a way to stop it.

This only started happening when I converted the python file to exe, before that the path was just `catgame/Assets/[sheet].png` since `.../Python/` was the working directory. But now since it is in exe form, that didn't work as I'm assuming that the way pygame interprets paths is different to how exes do it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

All of the code where the error will happen:

```
        catSheet = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\squid\OneDrive\Documents\programming\Python\catgame\Assets\CatSheet.png')
        placeholderSheet = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\squid\OneDrive\Documents\programming\Python\catgame\Assets\Placeholders.png')
        iconSheet = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\squid\OneDrive\Documents\programming\Python\catgame\Assets\IconsSheet.png')
        shopSheet = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\squid\OneDrive\Documents\programming\Python\catgame\Assets\ShopSpriteSheet.png')
        bedSheet = pygame.image.load('C:\\Users\squid\OneDrive\Documents\programming\Python\catgame\Assets\CatBedSheet.png')
```

I tried different formatting of the path, backslash, forward slash, etc. I expected these to atleast give a different error or fix it altogether, but the error did not change.

Comment: You should use raw strings (`r'...'`) when working with windows paths.

Comment: run your python code inside of assets, and call path as `('./[image_name].png]')`

Comment: You're asking for trouble with all those single backslashes.  Either use raw strings `r'c:\some\path'`, or use forward slashes `'c:/some/path'`

Comment: My own answer doesnt allow me to set it as correct for some odd reason, but thanks for the help everyone, got it working now

Comment: With modern pythons, using `/` as the path separator works on windows also. That should work for you.

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, extract a [mcve], which you provide along with the output it produces in your question. Don't use images if the output is text.